# Shared routes in different layouts react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `React` app with two layouts: `GuestLayout` and `AuthLayout`. Each of one renders a `Navbar`, and `Outlet` and a `Footer` depending if the user is logged:

AuthLayout.tsx

```
interface Props {
  isAllowed: boolean
  redirectPath: string
  children: JSX.Element
}

export const AuthLayout = ({ isAllowed, redirectPath, children }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation()

  if (!isAllowed) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace state={{ from: location }} />
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      <Navbar />
      <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
        {children || <Outlet />}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

GuestLayout.tsx

```
export const GuestLayout = () => (
  <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
    <GuestNavbar />
    <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
      <Outlet />
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
)
```

The `Footer`(used in both layouts), display a series of links that can be visited either the user is logged or not, and I don't know hot to do it properly. Here is my router:

app.tsx

```
<Route element={<GuestLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='recover-password' element={<RecoverPassword />} />
  <Route path='legal' element={<Outlet />}>
    <Route path='privacy' element={<LegalPageComponent page='privacyPolicy' />} />
    <Route path='notice' element={<LegalPageComponent page='legalNotice' />} />
  </Route>
</Route>

<Route
  element={<AuthLayout isAllowed={!!user} redirectPath='/login' children={<Outlet />} />}
>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
  <Route
    path='processes'
    element={
      <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
        <ProcessManagement />
      </Suspense>
    }
  />
  <Route path='management' element={<Outlet />}>
    <Route index element={<Management />} />
    <Route path='clients' element={<ClientManagement />} />
    <Route path='projects' element={<ProjectManagement />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='legal' element={<Outlet />}>
    <Route path='privacy' element={<LegalPageComponent page='privacyPolicy' />} />
    <Route path='notice' element={<LegalPageComponent page='legalNotice' />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

As you can see, I need the legal pages to be displayed in both layouts, but I don't know how to do it. If I do this, it goes always to `GuestLayout`.

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the `"/legal"` layout route and render the nested routes in the a new layout that conditionally renders the guest or auth UI.

It looks like the `"/"` index route rendering either `Login` or `Home` has the same issue. Render `Login` on ***only*** the `"/login"` path, and render a "catch-all" `path="*"` route to redirect users to `"/home"`. If the user is not authenticated then the `AuthLayout` will redirect them to `"/login"`.

Example:

```
interface Props {
  isAllowed: boolean;
}

export const CommonLayout = ({ isAllowed }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      {isAllowed ? <Navbar /> : <GuestNavbar />}
      <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>;
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<GuestLayout />}>
    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='recover-password' element={<RecoverPassword />} />
  </Route>

  <Route
    element={<AuthLayout isAllowed={!!user} redirectPath='/login' />}
  >
    <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
    <Route
      path='processes'
      element={
        <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
          <ProcessManagement />
        </Suspense>
      }
    />
    <Route path='management'>
      <Route index element={<Management />} />
      <Route path='clients' element={<ClientManagement />} />
      <Route path='projects' element={<ProjectManagement />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>

  <Route element={<CommonLayout />}>
    <Route path='legal'>
      <Route
        path='privacy'
        element={<LegalPageComponent page='privacyPolicy' />}
      />
      <Route
        path='notice'
        element={<LegalPageComponent page='legalNotice' />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Route>

  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

Since the guest and auth layouts really only differ in which header they render, UI-wise, it may be an improvement to instead render all routes into the `CommonLayout` to get the conditional rendering of one header or the other, and remove the UI/visual markup from `AuthLayout` so it's only handling the auth logic.

Example:

```
interface Props {
  isAllowed: boolean;
}

export const CommonLayout = ({ isAllowed }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      {isAllowed ? <Navbar /> : <GuestNavbar />}
      <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>;
  );
};
```

```
interface Props {
  isAllowed: boolean;
  redirectPath: string;
}

export const AuthLayout = ({ isAllowed, redirectPath }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation()

  return isAllowed
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to={redirectPath}
        replace
        state={{ from: location }}
      />
    );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<CommonLayout />}>
    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='recover-password' element={<RecoverPassword />} />

    <Route path='legal'>
      <Route
        path='privacy'
        element={<LegalPageComponent page='privacyPolicy' />}
      />
      <Route
        path='notice'
        element={<LegalPageComponent page='legalNotice' />}
      />
    </Route>

    <Route
      element={<AuthLayout isAllowed={!!user} redirectPath='/login' />}
    >
      <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
      <Route
        path='processes'
        element={
          <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <ProcessManagement />
          </Suspense>
        }
      />
      <Route path='management'>
        <Route index element={<Management />} />
        <Route path='clients' element={<ClientManagement />} />
        <Route path='projects' element={<ProjectManagement />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. So, my logic rendering `children || <Outlet />` is not necesary

Comment: @Aw3same Nope, the route protection component rendering a `children` prop only makes sense if you need/wanted to wrap individual routed components (*I don't know why though, it's not very **DRY***) whereas rendering the `Outlet` component allows it to wrap entire groups of routes (*very **DRY** *).

Comment: And, why on F5 this always redirect to /home?

Comment: @Aw3same Hard to say from just the code in your post or my answer. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces that issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Sure, in this [stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t6gq7i?file=src%2Fhooks%2FuseUser.ts) you can find a similar repo. The only thing that changes is the hook useUser, where I replicate the behaviour. Doing this i'm thinking that the main problem is the asynchrony when i reload the page and i check if user exists on the routes

Comment: @Aw3same The code in your stackblitz was missing using the `AuthProvider` component, but other than this, reloading the page isn't sending the user anywhere, the page stays on the same URL path.

Comment: yes, it's true, sorry .I see it working, and I took the code in the example to my repo and is working, so the problem is in my actual code, where I use react-query (I left my actual code commented in the hook). I'll look for the error. Thanks!!

Comment: UPDATE: merging the `react-query` functions `login` and `isProfileLoaded` works fine, so it has to be something about react-query internal management

Comment: @Aw3same Is this related to the this post's topic of route layouts? If not and you have some other new and different issue then a new post on SO with the relevant details and [mcve] would be better than trying to sort it out here in comments.