# Cannot use useNavigate in custom hook with createBrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have this custom hook for login and logout

```js
export function useUser() {
    const { token, setToken, user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const {
        mutate: login,
        isLoading: isLoginLoading,
        isError: hasLoginError,
        
    } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: signIn,
        onSuccess: async (tokenResponse) => {
            sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', tokenResponse.access_token)
            sessionStorage.setItem('refresh_token', tokenResponse.refresh_token)
            setToken(tokenResponse.access_token)
            const user = await getUserProfile()
            setUser(user)
            sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user))
            navigate('/home')
        },
        onError: () => {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('access_token')
        }
    })

    const { mutate: logout } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: signOut,
        onMutate: () => {
            sessionStorage.clear()
            setToken(null)
            setUser(null)
        },
        onSuccess: async () => {
            navigate('/login')
        }
    })

    return {
        login,
        logout,     
        isLoginLoading,
        hasLoginError,
        userPermissions: token ? (jwt_decode(token) as TokenDecoded).authorities : [],
        user
    }
}
```

And I want to take advantange of the new data router with react-router-dom `createBrowserRouter` and try to create a breadcrumb. Before this I use `<BrowserRouter>` and it works fine, but with this new approach, and because of the use of protected routes, I get the error.

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.

I perfectly understand the error, but I don't know  how to make it work. This is related with another issue that I post [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122011/shared-routes-in-different-layouts-react) and with a similar issue [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443583/getting-error-with-createbrowserrouter-usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-co). Here is my code :

`CommonLayout.tsx and AuthLayout.tsx`

```js
export const CommonLayout = ({ isAllowed }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
            {isAllowed ? <Navbar /> : <GuestNavbar />}
            <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
                <Outlet />
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export const AuthLayout = ({ isAllowed, redirectPath, children }: Props) => {
    const location = useLocation()

    return isAllowed ? (
        children ?? <Outlet />
    ) : (
        <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace state={{ from: location }} />
    )
}
```

And the new approach that I want:

```js
export function App() {
    const { user, userPermissions } = useUser()
    const router = createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
            <>
                <Route element={<CommonLayout isAllowed={!!user} />}>
                    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
                    <Route element={<AuthLayout isAllowed={userPermissions.includes('PERMISSION_1')} redirectPath='/login' />}>
                        <Route
                            path='home'
                            element={
                                <>
                                    <Breadcrumbs />
                                    <h1>Home</h1>
                                </>
                            }
                            handle={{ crumb: () => 'Home' }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path='tracking'
                            element={
                                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                                    <Breadcrumbs />

                                    <Tracking />
                                </Suspense>
                            }
                            handle={{ crumb: () => 'Tracking' }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path='cleaning'
                            element={
                                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                                    <Breadcrumbs />

                                    <Cleaning />
                                </Suspense>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path='admin'
                            element={
                                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                                    <Breadcrumbs />
                                    <Admin />
                                </Suspense>
                            }
                            handle={{ crumb: () => 'Admin' }}
                        />
                    </Route>
                </Route>
                <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/home' replace />} />
            </>
        )
    )
    return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}
```

As you can see, I need the `user` because some routes need it, but importing the hook throws the error. How can I avoid this?

The first approach is removing the `useNavigate` from the hook, useUser.

A second one is modify the layouts, so that the layouts import the hooks and receive as params something like a permission (in case of permissions) and a condition (in case I need it)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `useUser` calls `useNavigate` which depends on the router context, so `useUser` can only be called in a component within the RouterProvider.

Comment: Idk how to fix your case with minimal changes but if login is required on any path, you could wrap the entire `App` with an Auth component that displays a login page regardless of any routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useUser` hook can only be called within a routing context provided by a router, so it will need to be moved.

> A second one is modify the layouts, so that the layouts import the
> hooks and receive as params something like a permission (in case of
> permissions) and a condition (in case I need it).

This is the method I'd recommend. The `useUser` hook is already reading what I assume is a single global `AuthContext` value, so from what I can see it's completely safe to push the `useUser` hook calls down the ReactTree to the components that need it.

Update the layout components to access the `useUser` hook value and pass in the static data as props.

```
export const CommonLayout = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      {!!user ? <Navbar /> : <GuestNavbar />}
      <main className='flex-1 min-h-max p-8 bg-slate-100 dark:bg-neutral-800'>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export const AuthLayout = ({ children, redirectPath, roles = [] }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { userPermissions } = useUser();

  const isAllowed = userPermissions.some(permission => roles.includes(permission));

  return isAllowed ? (
    children ?? <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace state={{ from: location }} />
  );
}
```

Update the layout route components accordingly. `CommonLayout` doesn't consume any props now, and `AuthLayout` is passed an array of roles/permissions. The `useUser` hook call is removed.

```
export function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <>
        <Route element={<CommonLayout />}>
          <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route
            element={(
              <AuthLayout roles={['PERMISSION_1']} redirectPath='/login' />
            )}
          >
            <Route
              path='home'
              element={
                <>
                  <Breadcrumbs />
                  <h1>Home</h1>
                </>
              }
              handle={{ crumb: () => 'Home' }}
            />
            <Route
              path='tracking'
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                  <Breadcrumbs />
                  <Tracking />
                </Suspense>
              }
              handle={{ crumb: () => 'Tracking' }}
            />
            <Route
              path='cleaning'
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                  <Breadcrumbs />
                  <Cleaning />
                </Suspense>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path='admin'
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                  <Breadcrumbs />
                  <Admin />
                </Suspense>
              }
              handle={{ crumb: () => 'Admin' }}
            />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/home' replace />} />
      </>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```